# How can I get the beginning of the page of a memory address?

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, virtual

I am trying to get the beginning of the page, which my memory address is stored in. How can I do that? (Windows x64)

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What is the actual problem you need to solve? And what makes you think you can actually access that memory without risking undefined behavior?

Comment: Well, you could AND off the low bits of the address to get the 4k base address, but whether you can do much with it is another matter - see @Someprogrammerdude comment:(

Comment: [VirtualQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery) could be what you want

Answer (score 0):

First step is to find out the size of the memory page. There is no standard way to get the size of the memory page in C++. Consult documentation of the target operating system.

With the size of the page known, we need to align the given pointer to the edge of the page size. There is a standard function `std::align` which almost does what we want, except it aligns forwards the end of the page rather than back to the beginning. We can simply adjust  one page backwards:

```
inline void*
align_back(void* address, std::size_t alignment) noexcept
{
    void* aligned = address;
    std::size_t space = alignment;
    std::align(alignment, 1, aligned, space);
    return address == aligned
        ? aligned
        : static_cast<char*>(aligned) - alignment;
}

// example
void* beginning = align_back(address, page_size);
```

Or, we can rely a bit on implementation dependent details and assume that alignment of a reinterpreted integer matches the alignment of the pointer:

```
inline void*
align_back(void* ptr, std::size_t alignment) noexcept
{
    std::uintptr_t ptr_int = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(ptr);
    std::size_t remainder = ptr_int % alignment;
    return static_cast<char*>(ptr) - remainder;
}
```

This tends to produce better assembly in my testing.